# appropriate AWS architecture for xml->html converter, server?

Tags: html, xml, amazon-web-services

I'm new to AWS, and I need a little help choosing the proper architecture from the seemingly endless array of services. Can anyone give me a suggestion?

Basically, I'm trying to replace an old PHP server that does the following:

1. Reads XML from a URL. (it's data about rental properties)
2. Transforms the XML into HTML, reordering and adding a bit of styling via CSS.
3. Serves the HTML through Apache. (My customer has a self-designed Wix site that shows these results in an iframe.) I cache the HTML for 12 hours at a time, so that I'm not hammering the XML host in #1 more than twice/day.

What would be a simple way to replicate this simple parse/cache/serve setup in AWS? The data being parsed and served is very small, btw - up to 100 MB per day.

Edit: I'm not looking to keep the old PHP code. Any mainstream language should be fine.

Comment: Do you want to keep using the current PHP code? Or do you want to redesign/rewrite the service entirely?

Comment: I don't mind a rewrite. Any mainstream language should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use PHP then you could move your service to an EC2 server with few if any changes required to your code. You could also use Elastic Beanstalk for this which manages many of the AWS services for you, including the EC2 server.

Amazon also recently released the Lightsail service, which is similar to a VPS service and would definitely be easier to get started with than EC2.

If you are OK rewriting the code and are interested in a "serverless" model which might save you lots of money over a traditional server hosting model, you could look into AWS Lambda. Lambda doesn't currently support PHP, so you would have to rewrite your code in one of the languages it does support (Python, NodeJS, Java or C#).

Comment: You may also want to consider saving the rendered HTML to an S3 bucket configured to statically host websites.  It sounds like this setup could be completely serverless (Lambda + S3), and very cheap to run.